# Split a data frame into several cells on a specific string

Tags: r, string, dataframe, stringr

I have a data frame in R that is basically this,a body of text with a line brake string (\r\n) sprinkled through out :

```
 df <- data.frame (text  = c("non consectetur a erat nam at lectus urna duis convallis convallis tellus id interdum velit laoreet id donec ultrices tincidunt arcu non sodales neque sodales ut etiam sit amet nisl purus in mollis nunc sed id semper risus in hendrerit gravida rutrum quisque non tellus orci ac auctor augue mauris augue neque gravida in fermentum et sollicitudin ac orci phasellus egestas \r\n tellus rutrum tellus pellentesque eu tincidunt tortor aliquam nulla facilisi cras fermentum odio eu feugiat pretium nibh ipsum consequat nisl vel pretium lectus quam id leo in vitae turpis massa sed elementum tempus egestas sed sed risus pretium quam vulputate dignissim suspendisse in est ante in nibh mauris cursus mattis molestie a iaculis \r\n at erat pellentesque adipiscing commodo elit at imperdiet dui accumsan sit amet nulla facilisi morbi tempus iaculis urna id volutpat lacus laoreet non curabitur gravida arcu ac \r\n tortor dignissim convallis aenean et tortor at risus viverra adipiscing at in tellus integer feugiat scelerisque varius morbi enim nunc faucibus a pellentesque sit amet porttitor eget dolor morbi non arcu "))
```

How can I split this string into several dataframe entires each time the page break character (\r\n) appears?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The R base **strsplit()** function can be used to split text data into separate strings based on the page break character you mentioned ("\r\n"). The resulting object is a list that you can bind the list into a data frame:

```
df_list <- strsplit(df$text, "\r\n")
df_split <- data.frame(text = unlist(df_list))
```

Answer (score 2):

We could use `separate_longer_delim`

```
library(tidyr)
separate_longer_delim(df, text, delim = "\r\n")
```

Comment: Note `separate_longer_delim` needs the most recent `tidyr` version. It is really a cool feature. Usually I used this: `separate_rows(df, text, sep = "\r\n")`. Many thanks for sharing @akrun.